# Change fold icon colors in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I recently started using Material theme for Sublime and it's great except for the fold icons in the gutter. The color of the icons match the background color too closely and so they're a bit hard to see. I wanted to know if there's a way to change the color of these icons specifically? The background color could be changed, but doing so would mean having to change every other color value to match the new background which doesn't really make sense. Any help on how to make the fold code icons more visible would be greatly appreciated.